# How does one do checksum verification of network transmitted data

Tags: network-programming, udp, network-protocols, error-correction, error-checking

I am makign my own 'protocol' where I have to design the header. I understand how to verify the integrity of the first header I sent..

What I'm confused about is how does one verify the integrity of the data? Do I transmit a header appended to the front of the data that will contain the checksum of the header + the data frament itself, so the server knows to re-transmit it if it's wrong?

Or is there a way to be able to verify the data hasn't been damaged via some extra prepping in the beginning?

Comment: Personally, I'd compute the checksum of the data, and include that checksum value in the header.  I assume you're using a TCP stream (vs. a series of UDP datagrams) for each "data" transmission.

Comment: Actually a UDP stream. With custom headers. Got no choice in this

Comment: UDP already does checksum ing and validation, unless you disable it. No need to add your own.

Comment: The thing is that I only use a UDP stream, but I'm simulating the use of a custom protocol. So yes, I consider it disabled.

Comment: how is "verifying the integrity" of the first header any different from any later packet/datagram?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppU41c15Xho gives a nice intro to how checksums work (i.e. in UDP) but you might think about something stronger like a CRC or even a cryptographic hash